# Spring Security 6 using form login authentication with json payload request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization

How is one supposed to specify a custom a ServerFormLoginAuthenticationConverter in ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec when it is hard coded and there is no easy access to the authentication filter.

```
      MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher htmlMatcher = new MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher(new MediaType[]{MediaType.TEXT_HTML});
      htmlMatcher.setIgnoredMediaTypes(Collections.singleton(MediaType.ALL));
      ServerHttpSecurity.this.defaultEntryPoints.add(0, new DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint.DelegateEntry(htmlMatcher, this.authenticationEntryPoint));
      AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(this.authenticationManager);
      authenticationFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationMatcher(this.requiresAuthenticationMatcher);
      authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(this.authenticationFailureHandler);
      authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationConverter(new ServerFormLoginAuthenticationConverter());
      authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(this.authenticationSuccessHandler);
      authenticationFilter.setSecurityContextRepository(this.securityContextRepository);
      http.addFilterAt(authenticationFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.FORM_LOGIN);
```

Comment: Why do you want to customize `ServerFormLoginAuthenticationConverter`? Form login is for forms within HTML pages. Forms are not sending JSON. If your frontend is a JavaScript client you can still send form parameters. JavaScrip supports it. Why do you want to send JSON?

Comment: i do have a java script client and i know it supports form parameters, the rest of the api endpoints are using json content and this one sticks out.

Comment: That is the only reason? I would change the JavaScript code to use form parameter. It seems the easiest way. However, maybe someone else will give you an (better) answer. Good luck.

Comment: i would go with sending form parameters, its so much easier that trying to do custom security